# rails 4 app and stripe javascript not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am not the best at javascript and have been really confused on why my coffeescript is not retreiving the stripe token. I checked the error and it said card returned nil. I noticed that if I refill out the credit card information on the error page it works fine?

Here is the url to create a subscription /subscriptions/new?plan_id=1

the is a credit card error and it directs to /subscriptions/

If I fill out the credit card details on this page, then it works and create subscription on stripe. I am receiving this error on pages that are not my stripe form view and might be causing the problem

I am receiving this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined subscriptions.js?body=1:5
(anonymous function) subscriptions.js?body=1:5
fire jquery.js?body=1:3049
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:3161
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js?body=1:434
completed
```

Here is my view

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
<h1 class="callout callout-info">Signing up for <%= @subscription.plan.name %> Plan</h1>
<div class="poweredby">
  <span><%= image_tag("/images/stripepower.png", :alt => "Safe with stripe", :class => "stripepower") %></span>
  <span class="stripepower_description">Secure, Reliable, & Simple</span>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
      <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
        <div class="error_messages">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => @useremail %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :subscription_status, :value => "active" %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

      <% if @subscription.stripe_card_token.present? %>
        Credit card has been provided.
      <% else %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
        <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month", class: "form-control"} %>
        <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year", class: "form-control expirationdate"} %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <div id="stripe_error">
        <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Subscribe", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my coffee script file thanks to rails cast

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

subscription =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_subscription').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        subscription.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_subscription')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Comment: I found out that the stripe javascript can't just be on my view page, I included it on my application layout page in the header, but it causes a lot of errors with boostrap dropdown and even threw out weird erros on my check out page. Still need help on how to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: This is really sad that it took me this long to figure it out, but turbolinks was stopping my page from reloading javascript. It has caused problems before with others, so I removed it from gem file and everything is working. I heard jquery turbolinks is a good alternative, but for right now I am going to pass.

Comment: All you need to do is disable turbolinks for the link that takes you to the page with the Javascript - I had the same problem as you

Comment: `<%= link_to 'Display Text', link_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>`

Comment: @tommyd456 thanks for the example. I fought this for hours. Now its working fine.

Comment: @tommyd456's solution is the best one -- removing turbolinks completely for this particular thing is throwing the baby out with the bath water. It's sad that so many people just remove turbolinks and miss out on the huge speed boost (especially with transition caching) when simply RTFM would clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the Stripe javascript on the checkout page only, you could wrap Ryan Bates' coffeescript in a `if` statement.

```
if typeof(Stripe) != "undefined"
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()
```